# How will this Stack Exchange differ from competitor sites like Quora and Reddit AskScience?

Tags: discussion

What are some ideas that you have? And what will be the primary topics here?

Answer (score 7):

[Reddit AskScience](http://www.reddit.com/r/askscience) is a popular-science site: its goal is the "promotion of scientific literacy". If you look at the questions there, they are higher-level questions that would make sense to a layman.

In contrast, biology.stackexchange.com is a site by experts and for experts. The StackExchange engine can better accomodate the long tail of questions that are on a narrow topic.

Comment: I agree in general, but I think layman questions should still be allowed. See this question for more discussion: http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/17/should-we-encourange-the-relevant-questions-from-non-professionals